# mongo query - find similar items using hash

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Note: I understand this is not performant query to do.
This is just curiosity on how to do the search.

---

In mongo, I am storing hash that represent the object I insert.

```
{
  "a": 694695,
  "b": 24654,
  "t": 1693920660000,
   ...
  'hash': "humX124"

},
```

When I search for some object I calculate the hash first and look for the hash in the DB.

Using the hash, how to filter out similar items?

**Similarity** can be found by calculating Hamming Distance/Edit distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

High Edit distance = very different hashes = very diff objs

Low edit distance = similar hashes = similar objs

Is there some mongo query we can come up with to query similar items by passing the EditDistance(String,String) function and the edit distance minimum filter to the mongo query?

**example**

**hashes** : hum123, humX124, dog345, donkey566

**searching for similar item to**  : hum024

**Edit distance max** : 2

**result** : objects that have hash **hum123** & **humX124**

- because they have edit distance of 2;  to get to the search term hum024

thanks

Comment: A typical behavior of a **hash** function is to produce completely different result for slightly different input values. Thus your question does not make much sense.

Comment: In my case the hash function concatenates specific fields to get to diff hash results. the only reason the hashes would collide is because the items are identical.  The idea is to filter similar items on specific feature, while the items are diff in some other features.